# IIS and pre-compressed assets with zopfli

Tags: javascript, .net, iis, deployment

I am interested in experimenting with zopfli to densely compress my css/static html/js files.  I'm familiar with IIS's static compression (as configured in web.config), but zopfli produces a gzip file.  If I send say, a .js file in to zopfli, and get a gzip out.  How do I deploy the files in a way that they will be interpreted correctly by the browser?

Do I:
compress the .js file, and output it with a .js extension (even though it is a gzip), and then use a content header?    What's the sauce for that?

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the .gz extension after compression. You'll also want to configure APACHE or NGINX to no re-compress your already compressed files. A quick Google search can help you find up-to-date ways of doing that. It's not too difficult.